# Can one remove a courthouse without suffering unhappiness?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civ 5 the courthouse is needed to quell unhappiness once a city has been captured.

Can one ever remove the courthouse, and thus it's maintenance, without returning to a state of unrest?

Is there a point in time where the citizens become fully assimilated and indistinguishable from your own population?

Does destroying the original faction of the city have any impact on the courthouse and unrest?

Comment: I readded the gods-and-kings tag to denote we are talking about the latest version.  While there maybe no actual difference between the two versions regarding courthouses, that's not entirely clear as the expansion has quite a few tweaks throughout the game.

Comment: G&K is not the "latest version" but an expansion and in that expansion there is no modification to courthouse role.  I re-removed the tag.

Comment: @Mike - Really it's more than an expansion, it's also an update to the game, I want to be clear which version I'm talking about.  The [wiki confirms my view](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Civilization_V:_Gods_and_Kings): "The expansion includes new and **upgraded gameplay systems**".  It's really more than just an expansion, it plays like an update, so I have once again readded the tag.  Either way this is getting into purely pedantic territory so I ask that you respect my view.

Comment: Just a small sidenote: expansion tags are usually used if the question is specific to it; ie. G&K changes the way the courthouse works.  If it works exactly the same, both with and without G&K, then the tag isn't needed.

Comment: @fbueckert - A small note how does one know that before one asks the question?  Must I be a precog before I ask a question?  If not then isn't it valid to include the expansion in scope.  G&K seems to even include bug fixes.

Comment: Well, no, being omniscient isn't necessary.  But usually, if the community is removing the tag, it's a pretty good indicator that it's not necessary.  At this point, three other users have removed the tag; a general assumption can be made that the expansion changes nothing in the functionality of the courthouse.

Comment: If I came from a place of ignorance, isn't it possible that others will say "hey does that include the expansion as well"?  Doesn't that make the tag therefore valid.

Comment: The courthouse works the same, with or without the expansion; if someone asks, feel free to answer.

Comment: We're also coming off a massive tag cleanup effort, and trying to ensure they're used properly, so organization is in the forefront of many minds.  All we're trying to do is keep stuff organized properly.

Comment: I don't see how that invalidates my position, I want to cover the expansion, ergo the tag.

Comment: I think people just like to remove tags because its an easy way to participate without actually putting much effort into it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7808/discussion-between-fbueckert-and-mark-rogers)

Comment: Id rather have it said here, so people will understand why I'm insisting.

Comment: This isn't the place for extended discussion, like it says.  We can either take it to meta, or chat.  Either place is publicly available.

Comment: What more is there to say? what is your counter argument?

Comment: Unless the item in question has changed in the expansion, there is no reason to include the expansion tag in the question, because it is then an unnecessary distinction.

Comment: @RavenDreamer - but your assuming that's universally know, isn't that a fallacy.

Comment: @MarkRogers Nothing in your question explicitly refers to Gods and Kings. Therefore, the expansion tag is not used. If there *is* some change in the expansion that the asker is unaware of, the best answer is one which brings up, "Hey, this works differently depending on which game you're playing.". When in doubt, go for the more general option (i.e., no expansion tag). Please do not re-add the Gods & Kings tag to this question.

Comment: @RavenDreamer - Isn't that really a matter of preference?  What makes that strategy really any better?  Aren't you losing information that could easily be conveyed in a tag?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### TL:DR

To your three questions: no, no, and probably.

### Actual answer:

In Civ 5 the [courthouse](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Courthouse_%28Civ5%29) is indeed the only way to remove the unhappiness caused by occupation.

I wanted to check for myself if a city always stays "occupied" even after 100 turns or more, so I conducted some Lazy Science™!

First, I took my Babylonian empire, which had overrun Sydney around 100 turns ago (rough estimate, go Lazy Science!).

Here is a picture of the city before I sold the courthouse:

[image: pic1]

And here is my city after, notice that it is again marked as occupied, and that my Civ's happiness has decreased substantially.

[image: pic2]

Here you can see the unhappiness attributed to occupied cites:

[image: pic3]

I also took a German civ at turn 273, which had done away with the wretched Babylonians over 150 turns ago.

[image: pic]

I then took both Akkad and Babylon, and sold their courthouses.

You can see here that my Civ's happiness went from 8 to 2, and that both cites reverted to an occupied state.

[image: pic]
[image: pic]

So, it seems that in regard to your first two questions:

1. No, you shouldn't really get rid of courthouses.
2. No, occupied cites never really forget your transgressions against them.

Your third question, "Does destroying another Civ have an impact on their captured city" is a bit out of the scope of my answer (that and it would require more Lazy Science than I'd want to do right now). From my poor and easily forgotten experience, I recall that destroying a Civ will make both their captured cites and other Civs a little bit more miffed with you. I don't know if a city being puppeted would affect this.

If you want a more in-depth answer, you could try asking this as a separate question.

Comment: I can confirm the answer to the third real quick. Will return with an answer.

Comment: You cannot technically destroy another civ in civ 5. It's always possible for another civ to return their capital back to them and the formerly-defeated civ will return. So I suspect the answer to three is also "no".

Comment: Confirmed. Even defeated civs. (Though to be fair, that regeneration clause only came in to play for Gods and Kings)

Comment: That's a lot of screenshots for lazy science!

Comment: Lazy Science is nothing if not thorough.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot destroy (former) capitals, unfortunately. Also, quick look around the internet seems to indicate that the unhappiness from annexing a city never disappears and as such, you will always need the courthouse.

Comment: Who is talking about destroying capitals?

Comment: @Sentry it's sort-of related in the sense that you can't completely get rid of a civilization, which was the 3rd part of the question.